# How to kill Cursed Revenants in Arx burning building

Tags: divinity-original-sin-2

I have met Cursed Revenants in Arx in burning building

> so far I have met monsters that would respawn up to 3 times after getting HP to 0 (four guys in graveyard)

these guys seen to respawn indefinitely, I have killed one around 10 times... and he just re appears again and again...

**How to kill Cursed Revenants in Arx burning building?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok so the trick is to remove all the burning surfaces from the building because they can only respawn there...

Get tornado spell (Aero 3), it removes cursed fire surfaces, so before fights just 'clean' the room and it will be a cake...

Also first give bless to all of your team and have source points ready.

I went North to Northeast section of building first ad cleared it all. Then you get to fight all 4 of them in the south part that is closer to the entrance..

Go to the second floor and use tornado or bless the ground under the guy and cast rain... then just kill him, if he makes new necrofire surfaces deal with them first then rinse and repeat

I have also made a video...

Hope this saves you some time